# Как запустить отладку с определенной страницы?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Ставлю в настройках VS Specific Page, затем выбираю из списка свою страницу, но при запуске получаю, что запрошенный ресурс не найден.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

VS подставляет лишний уровень Views и расширение .cshtml. Убрал и все заработало.